# How to make sense of `interpolateTransformCss`, `interpolateTransformSvg` in `d3-interpolate` with simple examples?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am studying the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/master/src/transform/index.js) of [`d3-interpolate`](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/master/README.md#interpolateTransformCss). I could vaguely follow the doc and src of  `interpolateTransformCss` and `interpolateTransformSvg`.

However, given basic knowledge of CSS and little knowledge on SVG, I could not figure out what exactly do these two functions produce without the help of some test examples (`d3-interpolate` repo does not provide test examples for these two functions).

Could anyone provide some simple examples which could demonstrate how these two functions work and what they try to achieve in action like those sample codes displayed in blockbuilder.org?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG elements can take a `transform` property. It might look something like this:

```
<circle transfrom="translate(20, 10) rotate(30)" r="10" />
```

Which means "move the circle to x=20 y=10 and rotate it 30 degrees".

Interpolators help with transitions. So if you transition that circle to a new position and rotation, like

```
<circle transfrom="translate(30, 20) rotate(40)" r="10" />
```

then an interpolator is needed. d3 transitions do that automatically, but the interpolator object is exposed to enable you to do your own interpolations as needed for your use case. So creating an interpolator for that circle might look like this:

```
var myInterpolator = d3.interpolateTransformSvg(
  "translate(20, 10) rotate(30)",
  "translate(30, 20) rotate(40)"
)
```

That d3 interpolator will detect that it needs to interpolate 3 numbers: 20, 10 and 30. Based on that, here's what you would get:

```
myInterpolator(0);   // returns "translate(20, 10) rotate(30)"
myInterpolator(1);   // returns "translate(30, 20) rotate(40)"
myInterpolator(0.5); // returns "translate(25, 11) rotate(35)"
```

I.e. the last example returns the appropriate transform halfway (0.5 of the way) between 0 and 1.

`d3.interpolateTransformCss` does the same thing but with CSS transforms, which serve the same purpose as SVG transform but are applied via `style` to non-SVG elements and have a slightly different format.

Answer (score 2):

In brief [affine transformation matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/affine-transformation.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) is not morphable  in the way suitable for meaningful transition (interpolation from state A to state B).

Let say we have initial identity transformation matrix that we need to transform to rotated one: 
[image: rotation by angle q]

Animated rotation means you need to animate angle but not each component of the matrix separately. So right way of matrix transition is to [decompose it to four basic operations](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/master/src/transform/decompose.js): translate, rotate, shear and scale. Having these independent transformations you can morph them independently and meaningfully and assemble them (multiply) into final single transformation matrix.

It seems that d3 code, instead of final `matrix()`, simply produces list of `rotate()`, `translate()`, etc. operations.

Check: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#interpolation-of-2d-matrices

Comment: Thanks @c-smile, now I see the use of `decompose` function. With my little background of math, a real example demonstrating the use of these two functions like those displayed on blockbuilder.org would be a greater help.